# decimal formatting, adding the $ symbol

Tags: java

hi im asked to compare files once i write my code, and 
in my file comparison, in myout1, compared to output 1.

(myout1) in my totalPrice i have 0.0, and the (output1) totalPrice is $0.00

is there something i should add to my code to add that money symbol?

ive tried decimal format fmt = new decimalFormat($0.00); ... or ($#.##), ive added this to myTostring methods as ... totalPrice + mny.format(totalPrice)

but when i print i get 0.$00 or 0.0.0$. . i just cant seem to move that $ symbol ahead

is there something im missing or over looking?

this is my code where i am adding this to

Comment: Hmm, what would this expression do `totalPrice + mny.format(totalPrice)` ... ?

Comment: "The Total Price:\t"  + totalPrice  + mny.format(totalPrice) .. this just prints $0.0$0 . . if i put it in front of totalPrice it prints $00.0. . but i want it to print $0.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful for you:

```
     System.out.println(DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(99.9));
```

It puts `$` on the beggining of the output.